# How to sort a DataGridView Column?

Tags: c#

I've created a DataTable as follows:

```
        accTable = new DataTable();
        accTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date"));
        accTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amt"));
        accTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item"));
```

and filling it by:

```
            foreach (DataRow myDataRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                DataRow accRow = accTable.NewRow();
                //code skipped

                accRow["Date"] = date.ToString("d"); //tried without converting to string also
                accRow["Amt"] = int.Parse(cells[1].ToString());
                accRow["Item"] = cells[2].ToString();

                accTable.Rows.Add(accRow);
            }
```

Then I'm binding a DataGridView to the DataTable accTable as follows:

```
            dataGridView1.DataSource = accTable;
```

How can I make the Date column sortable. By default, it is sorting alphabetically.
Where can I set the type of the column to DateTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column has a `DataType`. Have you tried setting that to `DateTime`?

```
var accTable = new DataTable();

var columnSpec = new DataColumn("Date");
columnSpec.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
accTable.Columns.Add(columnSpec);
```

Of course you can do this on one line (*thanks to BFree*):

```
accTable.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));
```

You bind this `DataTable` to a `DataGridView` and then for each column on the view set the `SortMode` property:

```
column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

I did have some code that did all this, but I converted it to use nullable types (including the DateTime fields) and it's not working as I expected any more. If I can get it working properly again I'll update this answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks I didb't know abt how the type property could be assigned!

Comment: All I need to do now is work out how to get the underlying type from my nullable type.

Comment: Just a small point; you can do this all in one line: accTable.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));

Comment: @BFree - true you can - I was just highlighting the Property

Answer (score -1):

For date data, we can use the following code:

```
dgv_transfer_from.Sort(dgv_transfer_from.Columns["Date_Out"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```