# sort on date column gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I got a gridview which auto generates columns. One of the columns is a date field.
Somehow, i cant sort the date field. It's being interpreted as a string.

The data comes out a database. The datatype there is set on datetime.

This is the code in the aspx file:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false"/>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realise this is a relatively old post but looking for a solution myself I figured this out.

If the `Date` is being populated as a string then you need to make sure it's not. To do this **create the data for the table as a `DataTable`** and when adding in the data use:

`dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));`

This sorts the **Date column** out just as you would like it.

Comment: hi, the project i was working on is no longer being developed. but since your explanation sounds like a solution to the problem i had, I'll mark your post as answered. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you Format a value (no matter what data type it is), the result is a String. Any operations on the result (such as sorting) work with a String.

You should directly sort the Datasource of the Gridview on Database side.

Comment: Its not up to me how to sort the grid. Its for the user. Some times it needs to be acsending and sometimes it needs to be descending. I added the Formatter after googling for this problem. It wasn't in the code in the first place. Was worth a try.

Comment: You could save the currentSortDirection in the ViewState, check if the new sortexpression is the same as the old and then switch the direction.

Comment: Why can't you sort the DataTable after the data have been loaded from the database? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857115/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-column

Comment: the data gets sorted in a few different ways by the user. date is one of them. so you have to agree with me that this has to be done at 'run time'.