# How to sort a DataGridView column (tied to a BindingSource) by date?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I've got a DataGridView which, amongst others, has columns containing dates. Unfortunately, the dates are in the format DD.MM.YYYY and the whole value is in 1 column, which is the common date format here in Europe. The DGV is tied to a BindingSource which is capable of sorting and advanced sorting.

The problem is the following: If I just use the standard sorting of the DGV, the dates are viewed as strings (they're displayed in a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) and thus sorted by day->month->year but of course I'd want exactly the opposite; I want them sorted chronologically.

So, is there a way to sort this columns the way I want them to?

- By far the easiest way would be to be able to use the SortCompare
  event of the DGV but apparently that can't be done if the DGV is tied
  to a DataSoruce.
- Of course I used Google and I always get the "use the Sort property for advanced sorting" solution. The BindingSource that's tied to the DGV indeed does support sorting and advanced sorting but as I understand it, this just gives me the possibility to e.g. sort by multiple columns and doesn't provide a way to make it sort the date column by year->month->day (or in more general terms allows me to implement a kind of compare function). Or am I missing something?

What options do I have to achiev what I want? When explaining, please keep in mind that I'm -althoug not new to programming- new to this Windows Forms stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this post and see if it helps: [DGV Sort Using Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857115/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-column)

Comment: That absolutely did the trick, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
private void DataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Name == "YourColumnName") //<== this must be your date column name
    {
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(e.CellValue1);
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(e.CellValue2);
        e.SortResult = System.DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will give you an ideea. First I'm setting up the data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DateOfBirth", typeof(DateTime));

dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(1981, 10, 29));
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(1984, 8, 12));
dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(1982, 9, 7));

bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
```

Now using the ColumnHeaderMouseClick we will perform sorting on the first column:

```
private SortOrder _sortDirection;

    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
            string sort = string.Empty;
            switch (_sortDirection) {
                case SortOrder.None:
                    _sortDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
                    sort = "asc";
                    break;
                case SortOrder.Ascending:
                    _sortDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
                    sort = "desc";
                    break;
                case SortOrder.Descending:
                    _sortDirection = SortOrder.None;
                    sort = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }

            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = _sortDirection;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort)) {
                bindingSource1.Sort = "DateOfBirth " + sort;
            } else {
                bindingSource1.RemoveSort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!